# Using jBLAS with NVBLAS

Tags: java, blas, nvblas, jblas

I have compiled jBLAS with NVBLAS with a somewhat hacky solution, since the configure script was not correctly finding the libraries. I manually edited the `configure.out` file of jBLAS like so, to include the NVBLAS libraries.

```
BUILD_TYPE=nvblas
CC=gcc
CCC=c99
CFLAGS=-fPIC -DHAS_CPUID
F77=gfortran
FOUND_JAVA=true
FOUND_NM=true
INCDIRS=-Iinclude -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
LAPACK_HOME=./lapack-lite-3.1.1
LD=gcc
LDFLAGS=-shared
LIB=lib
LINKAGE_TYPE=static
LOADLIBES=-Wl,-z,muldefs /home/linyi/jblas/lapack-lite-3.1.1/lapack_LINUX.a /usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64/libnvblas.so.11 /home/linyi/jblas/lapack-lite-3.1.1/blas_LINUX.a -lgfortran
MAKE=make
NM=nm
OS_ARCH=amd64
OS_ARCH_WITH_FLAVOR=amd64/sse3
OS_NAME=Linux
RUBY=ruby
SO=so
```

I then ran the commands `make clean all` and `mvn clean package` as documented [here](https://github.com/jblas-project/jblas/blob/main/INSTALL). The tests pass successfully, but the program results in a segmentation fault on exit.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.jblas.TestEigen
[NVBLAS] NVBLAS_CONFIG_FILE environment variable is set to '/home/linyi/nvblas.conf'
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.569 sec
Running org.jblas.TestComplexFloat
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running org.jblas.TestDecompose
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
Running org.jblas.TestBlasDouble
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
Running org.jblas.TestBlasDoubleComplex
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running org.jblas.TestSingular
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
Running org.jblas.TestDoubleMatrix
Tests run: 37, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.022 sec
Running org.jblas.TestSolve
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running org.jblas.TestBlasFloat
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running org.jblas.TestFloatMatrix
Tests run: 37, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec
Running org.jblas.SimpleBlasTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running org.jblas.ranges.RangeTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running org.jblas.TestGeometry
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running org.jblas.ComplexDoubleMatrixTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
-- org.jblas INFO Deleting /tmp/jblas4383455253907276334/libjblas.so
-- org.jblas INFO Deleting /tmp/jblas4383455253907276334/libjblas_arch_flavor.so
-- org.jblas INFO Deleting /tmp/jblas4383455253907276334
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fa1f6bb96b1, pid=8063, tid=8072
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.8+10) (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libcublas.so.11+0xa096b1]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or dumping to /home/linyi/jblas/jblas/core.8063)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/linyi/jblas/jblas/hs_err_pid8063.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts
#
Aborted (core dumped)

Results :

Tests run: 122, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I decided to run `mvn clean package -DskipTests` as it seemed that the tests were passing fine, just that the program causes a segmentation fault on termination. When I used the libary in my Java project however, `nvblas.log` reveals that although NVBLAS was intercepting the calls to the BLAS routines, they were in fact being executed on the CPU instead of the GPU. Running `nvprof --print-gpu-summary` with my program also resulted in the same conclusion.

```
#
==7711== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:  100.00%  1.8240us         1  1.8240us  1.8240us  1.8240us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
======== Error: Application received signal 134
```

And the contents of `nvblas.log` are as follows:

```
[NVBLAS] Using devices :0
[NVBLAS] Config parsed
[NVBLAS] dgemm[cpu]: ta=N, tb=N, m=1, n=1, k=1
[NVBLAS] dsyr2k[cpu]: up=U, ta=N, n=24, k=28
[NVBLAS] dsyr2k[cpu]: up=U, ta=N, n=32, k=28
[NVBLAS] dsyr2k[cpu]: up=U, ta=N, n=26, k=28
[NVBLAS] dsyr2k[cpu]: up=U, ta=N, n=22, k=28
[NVBLAS] dsyr2k[cpu]: up=U, ta=N, n=20, k=28
[NVBLAS] dsyr2k[cpu]: up=U, ta=N, n=26, k=28
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=U, ta=N, di=U, m=52, n=31
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=U, ta=N, di=U, m=54, n=31
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=L, ta=T, di=N, m=52, n=31
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=L, ta=T, di=N, m=54, n=31
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=U, ta=N, di=U, m=60, n=31
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=U, ta=T, di=U, m=54, n=31
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=U, ta=T, di=U, m=52, n=31
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=L, ta=T, di=N, m=60, n=31
[NVBLAS] dsyr2k[cpu]: up=U, ta=N, n=22, k=28
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=U, ta=T, di=U, m=60, n=31
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=U, ta=N, di=U, m=54, n=22
[NVBLAS] dgemm[cpu]: ta=T, tb=N, m=54, n=22, k=31
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=U, ta=N, di=U, m=60, n=28
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=U, ta=N, di=U, m=52, n=20
[NVBLAS] dtrmm[cpu]: si=R, up=L, ta=T, di=N, m=54, n=22
[NVBLAS] dgemm[cpu]: ta=T, tb=N, m=60, n=28, k=31
[NVBLAS] dgemm[cpu]: ta=T, tb=N, m=52, n=20, k=31
[NVBLAS] dgemm[cpu]: ta=N, tb=T, m=31, n=54, k=22
. . .
```

I am really at a loss as to what to do, I hope someone can offer any advice, this seems to be really poorly documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out.

```
nm libjblas.so | grep -is dgemm
         U cblas_dgemm
         U dgemm_@@libnvblas.so.11
```

This shows that the libary is indeed linking correctly. I then proceeded to run the built in benchmark of jBlas, by just running `java -jar jblas.jar` where `jblas.jar` is the compiled library, and apparently GPU offload only occurs for large matrices, as no gpu calls were made when `n=10` or `n=100` but `nvblas.log` logged GPU computation at `n=1000`. This was very confusing for me, I hope this helps anyone else struggling with this issue.